# How to use Docker images in jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins

I created one docker image.

Docker image contain `java, node ,npm , git maven.`

I want to use this docker image in  jenkins at job build time for,

1. git clone
2. Use docker java as JAVA_HOME in jenkins.
3. build project using docker image maven.

How to configure this?

Comment: Do you have Jenkins also running in same container?

Comment: did you look at the docker plugin for jenkins ?
 : https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin

Comment: @Ashan Jenkins is not in same container.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the machine where jenkins is running has docker installed, you can run your container on the same machine and execute the above commands inside this container.

```
docker exec -it <container-name> git clone http://...
docker exec -it <container-name> mvn clean install ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create Docker image as a part of some stage in your Jenkins pipeline.

After that you can use the docker image in your same Jenkins pipeline:

```
stage ("Build docker image") {
            sh "docker build -t myProject ."

        }

        stage ("Run application container") {
            sh "docker run -d -p 9090:9090 --name=myProject -e  myProject"
        }
```